# Angular PWA never entering into stable state

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, angular-service-worker, angular-pwa

The Angular application I'm working on never gets into stable state, basing on `ApplicationRef.isStable`, which only emits `false` once. According to [Angular docs](https://angular.io/api/core/ApplicationRef#isstable-examples-and-caveats):

> the application will never be stable if you start any kind of recurrent asynchronous task when the application starts (for example for a polling process, started with a setInterval, a setTimeout or using RxJS operators like interval);

So I've reviewed all usages of `setTimeout()`, `setInterval()` (none) and RxJS' `interval()`, which I delayed until `appRef.isStable` gives true and the same with SignalR (kind of websocket) connection, but it all didn't help. I was trying to use DevTools' Performance, Memory and LightHouse tools to find the source of this unwanted behavior, but the only running task I've seen (for the first half of second in Performance tab) was from zone.js and slightly growing JS Heap:
[image]

In the Network tab nothing happens except pending connection with Angular's `127.0.0.1:4200/sockjs-node/*/websocket` on dev server, which I guess is fine. The same behavior (except Angular's websocket) can be seen consistently on all production environments.

Is there any way to debug it in order to find a reason for that? Any other advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was caused by RxJS' [`windowTime()`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/windowtime) operator.

Answer (score 0):

Just to complete Daniel's anwser;

This behavior will happen every time a macrotask (`setInterval`, `setTimeout` etc.) is called in the bootstraping phase of your app and it looks like `windowTime` (like every other RxJS timed operators) uses one of them.